# Yammer embed showing feed does not exist error

Tags: yammer

Is anyone else having trouble with Yammer Embed today? We just noticed that all of our feeds are broken. The feed loads for about a minute, then breaks. Yammer error is "The feed you requested does not exist". Fiddler shows:
404, https://www.yammer.com/oauth2/access_token.json?client_id=&_=************ 404 (Not Found)